# Replacement for writing out entire domain?

Tags: php, html, hyperlink

I am in the process of creating a website that will eventually be moved to a different domain. Every link on the site currently starts with `http://www.mydomain.com/folder`. This means that when I move domain I will have to change each and every link. Is there a replacing method of this? Sorry that this is a very basic question, I wasn't quite sure what I was looking for. Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php try to read this and I think you can use `$_SERVER['your_file_name']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly; best way is to make it configurable. There should be a global variable:

```
HTTP_SERVER = 'http://www.mydomain.com/';
```

and when you want you build a link, you should use:

```
<a href="<?php echo HTTP_SERVER . 'folder'; ?>">Link To Folder</a>
```

But let's get back to your question;
You can use an IDE to search and replace in all of the files in a specific folder. I use Visual Studio which you can choose to search in entire project and replace. But if you want other quick solutions, the best one comes to my mind is Notepad++, you can open a bunch of files and search & replace among them. Another one is Sublime Text which is a great lightweight text-editor / IDE that i use.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an IDE to do a global search and replace across all files in the project.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring a `$base_url="www.domain.com/folder"` in your connection file which will be included in all pages. so that you can just change the base url there only. and when you want the link call it as `$base_url.'/page_name.php';`